# Decode Hex in middle of string

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

I have the following string: `12345\xaGood day`.

the chars `\xa` represent new line in hex.

Is there a generic function to decode all hex instances with their relevant ascii ?
I want the output to be
 `12345
  Good day`

I tried the following but it didn't help:

> System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text))

Comment: What if there are two encoded characters sequentially? That will be \xa\xa then? Can there be two-character sequences (\xAA)?

Comment: if it's valid hex, then it's allowed

Comment: so in 12345\xaaBad day "\xaaBa" will be interpreted as hex?

Comment: I see your point.
so it shouldn't